# Magento: Add Custom Option Button not working on Admin Side

Tags: php, magento

I am working on Magento community edition 1.8.0.0 and I have a problem adding a custom option to product. When I click on the "Add New Option" button nothing happens? And I have no clue why its happening.

[image: Image is Attached]

Comment: have you got any js error?

Comment: Nop. I am not getting errors. No JS and no PHP errors.

Comment: first check it will get click event using firebug.it will call this function if($('add_new_defined_option')){
Event.observe('add_new_defined_option', 'click', productOption.add.bind(productOption));
}

Comment: In which template file will I find this?

Comment: no you don't have to add this js but just check if is extcute or  not? using firebug?